# How to replace </body> and Insert a text before it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I am looking for Javascript (or jquery) code that can automatic replace :

```
</body>
```

by (for example ) :

```
<div>example text</div></body>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to change the content of an html page? dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to replace `</body>`? Instead of replacing, it's a better idea to append the `div` tag to the `body` tag, using the [`.append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('body').append('<div>example text</div>');
```

Comment: hi ProgramFOX . yes i want to replace </body . and insert text before in

Comment: @user2737385: Why, actually? It is a better idea to append HTML to the body tag. The result is the same.

Comment: tanks ProgramFOX its's right . how to use this code in html ?? :(

Comment: @user2737385: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: How should I use this code?

Comment: If you want to add the `div` tag after the page is ready, you can add this script in the `head` tag:

    `<script>$(function() {
          $('body').append('<div>example text</div>');
    });</script>`
Add this script tag to the `head` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try using google first.

You can use jquery 'append' function to do this. 
Read more here. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: hi PiotrC . i just want replace /body . Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Create the div tag with id in your html.

```
  <body>
     ------------
     <div id="sampleId"></div>
     -------------
  </body>
```

Use the following in your script.

```
    var div = document.getElementById('sampleId');

    div.innerHTML = 'example text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add that element dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "mydiv");

        div.className = "notice";
        div.style.display = "block";
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Extra stuff';
        // test case, append the div to the body
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to replace something in your page u can use this:

```
var page = $('html').html();
page = page.replace('</body>', '<div>Test</div></body>');
$('html').html(page);
```

But if  you want just add div to the body element use the code append(''); as suggested ProgramFOX

Comment: hi Alexsai. i test this code but It does not work :( how to use this code in html ?

Comment: i tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/9W7a3/ but i had to use p tag instead of body